# Jenkins publish over ssh can not recognize user inputs

Tags: jenkins, ssh, setting

I am trying to deploy a `spring-boot - gradle` project via Jenkins.

I put all arguments as [Push over SSH Guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) said, But somehow Jenkins did not recognize user inputs like screen shot below.

What would I do to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That red phrase is nothing but just a notice.

- Source files : file to send over SSH(In my case, the output file of spring boot)
- Remote prefix : directory where `Source files` are in jenkins workspace
- Remote directory : The directory to execute ssh command in target server
- Exec command : command to execute (`pwd` or `ls -al` is good to test)

I hope this summary can save time of others